# Understanding DQN Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

Im studying the deep q learning algorithm. You can see it in the picture here:
[DQN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHDBb.png)

I have a few questions about the deep q learning algorithm.
What do they mean with row 14: `If D_i = 0, set Y_i = ...`
They want me to take an action a' which maximizes the function Q which means i have to insert every action a in that state. 
If i have a1 and a2 I have to insert a1 and then a2 to test which gives me the maximum right? But the input of my networks are states. So how do I know which action maximizes my network? 
Do I have to look in the last layer. Where I have Q(s,a1) and
Q(s,a2) to look which one has a higher value and take that action?

 Like in this architecture
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to insert anything else but state in your NN. The OUTPUTS of your NN are the action-values per action. Given a state (input) the NN will output 4 action-values (outputs) assuming there are 4 available actions. Then you compare the resulting outputs and select the maximum one. Thats for the max operator. For the policy (line: 8), you need the argmax operator which means you need the action that results in the maximum value of Q. In other words having selected for example the max Q = Q(a1) the action that maximizes the Q is a1.

It might help you visualizing the NN output as a vector $\mathbf{q}=[q(a_1),q(a_2),q(a_3),q(a_4)]$. So you do have the action-value for every available action for a particular state. Now you can implement the max and argmax operators.

Comment: Thanks! Do I have to train it like that: Lets say my NN has the states s = [s1,s2,s3]. Do I give him all three inputs simultaneously. Or do I give him the three state inputs like: s1 and then s2 as input?

Comment: If my answer indeed answers your question please kindly consider ticking it as such :) For training, you need to train in batches: inputs: [s1,s2,s3] and targets [R1,R2,R3] where $R_i$ is the expected return from state s and performing action a. Please refer to any deepQ repos and debug step by step so you understand the process.